# setting a key in a component does not re-render the component on state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I have a component that has two children:

1. A component where the user inputs and select a topic
2. A component that renders results based on the topic selected in the previous component

So this is the code of the parent component:

```
import SearchBox from "../../components/SearchBox";
import Results from "../../components/Results";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedTopic: null,
        };
    }

    onSelectTopic = (topic) => this.setState({
        selectedTopic: topic,
    });

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBox
                    onSelectTopic={this.onSelectTopic}
                />
                <Results
                    key={this.state.selectedTopic && this.state.selectedTopic.id}
                    selectedTopic={this.state.selectedTopic}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Basically, the `SearchBox` component updates the state of the parent component that propagates the selection to the `Results` component.

The `Results` component has its own state, that I want to clear when a new selection is passed. Instead of using [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) in `Results` to clear its state I have added a key to `<Results key={...}/>` as in the snippet above.

I was expecting that every time the state in the parent component updates (ie, the `onSelectTopic` method is called above), the `Results` component will be recreated, but instead the component does not update at all. Am I missing something? If I remove its `key` property, `Results` updates as expected (ie without clearing its internal state, which is what I want to achieve by using the `key`)

Btw, I'm using [preact](https://preactjs.com/) instead of react, but my understanding is that the behaviour regarding the `key` property on components is the same.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what is explained in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@albertogasparin/forcing-state-reset-on-a-react-component-by-using-the-key-prop-14b36cd7448e)

Comment: just created a similar fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dogancan/n5u2wwjg/257933/
Looks good to me. Can you make sure that your selectedTopic.id exists and a valid key

Comment: I believe everything you said is good except `Results` won't be recreated every time, the component's render will be refreshed if `this.state.selectedTopic` changes. `key` should be irrelevant here. In general, you shouldn't have another state for tracking `selectedTopic` inside `Results`. Because this will simplify the logic. You can put a `console.log` inside `render()` inside `Results` component and see what you got.

Comment: `console.log` in `render()` of `Result` reveals that the function gets called (but interestingly, `componentDidUpdate()` is not called). Just to clarify what I want: `Results` has its own internal state holding information different than `selectedTopic` (ie, internal filters, etc). I want that state to be cleared every time a new topic is selected, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I'm now understanding what is happening: The `key` is in fact doing what I was describing. But because I had some logic inside `Results`'s `componentDidUpdate`, that logic was not running at all because the component was being recreated. I think just refactoring the conditions to trigger a state update should fix the problem

Comment: This is fixed now. The example above was working as expected, but it was the logic in `componentDidUpdate` that was preventing the component to behave as expected. Thanks for the pointers